# How to make a tsquery perform a partial match?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, psql

I have the following situation. In our database, our user has the ability to search part numbers as 'keywords'. Part numbers are attached as 'footnotes' which get attached to certain items. An example of a footnote of this nature would have a description of:

```
Part Number: 09C888
```

Our keyword search searches multiple tables through an incredibly fun set of LEFT JOINs eventually forming a ts_vector which then is used against a tsquery. Our current issue is that this methodology seems to only accept exact matches. Example:

```
select to_tsvector('Part Number: 09C888') @@ to_tsquery('09C888:*');
 ?column?
---------
 t
```

Using the full version of the part number as the search criteria works fine. However...

```
select to_tsvector('Part Number: 09C888') @@ to_tsquery('9C888:*');
 ?column?
----------
 f
```

Is there a way to modify the above tsquery item to match against 09C888 with values of 09C888 **AND** 9C888? Normally, I could do something similar with the LIKE construct, but we're currently using full text search for efficiency on large amounts of data. From perusing the postgresql documentation, I cannot figure out an easy way to do this. I am also hesitant to change the overall query since it's doing... well, its doing a lot of stuff of which the text matching is only one part of. (Obviously a potential place for improvement.)

**EDIT:**

I've actually figured out how to do this using a modified query

```
select to_tsvector('Part Number: 09C888') @@ to_tsquery('09C888|9C888:*');
```

Is there a better way to determine match than what I've listed above? Mostly because the solution in incredibly specific, but essentially these part numbers may or may not have leading 0s.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing the part number with leading zeroes removed in a separate column and search against that?

`+---------------------+-------+
| Part Number: 09C888 | 9C888 |
+---------------------+-------+`

```
CREATE INDEX footnote_part_number_txt_idx
ON footnotes (stripped_part_number text_pattern_ops);
```

then you can query (using the index)

```
SELECT footnote_str
FROM footnotes
WHERE stripped_part_number LIKE '9C88%'
```

See: http://petereisentraut.blogspot.se/2009/10/rethink-your-text-column-indexing-with.html

Comment: This is probably a good way to do under most circumstances. Ideally I'd like to be able to do this without any table changes, since this is a rare case for how we store this information ('Part Number: 09C888' is just a text note, and we have 'tons' of notes that don't describe part numbers.)